# rails minitest is driving me insane with PG::UniqueViolation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, minitest

Half of the time I'll be able to make my tests run. The other half they fail because of a uniqueness violation, the source of which I am unable to locate. Right now I am in the latter half. My error is this:

```
ItemTest#test_valid_setup:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_blobs_on_user_id_and_item_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, item_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "blobs" ("user_id", "item_id", "amount", "active", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
 test/models/item_test.rb:15:in `setup'
```

I have a `factories.rb`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
 factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
  email "test@test.com"
  username "test"
 end

 factory :item do
  owner
  image { loads file etc... }
  price 100
  ...
 end

 factory :blob, aliases: [:wanted, :collateral] do
  user
  item
  amount 0
  active true
 end
end
```

My `item_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'support/database_cleaner'

class ItemTest < Minitest::Test
 def setup
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  #create users
  @user1 = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: "a@pear.com", username: "barnyard")
  @user2 = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: "bo@ichi.com", username: "ponygrl")
  @user3 = FactoryBot.create(:user, email: "ho@ho.com", username: "hon")

  #create items
  @item1 = FactoryBot.create(:item, owner: @user1)
  @item2 = FactoryBot.create(:item, owner: @user2, price: 101)
  @item3 = FactoryBot.create(:item, owner: @user3, price: 102)

  #create blobs
  @blob1 = FactoryBot.create(:blob, user: @user1, item: @item1, amount: @item1.price, active: false)
  @blob2 = FactoryBot.create(:blob, user: @user2, item: @item2, amount: @item2.price, active: false)
  @blob3 = FactoryBot.create(:blob, user: @user3, item: @item3, amount: @item3.price, active: false)
 end

 def teardown
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end
end
```

And then an `item.rb`

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 after_create :create_blobs

 private
 def create_blobs
  blob = Blob.new(user_id: self.owner.id, item_id: self.id, amount: self.price)
  blob.save
 end
end
```

A little background: A `User` creates an `Item` which in turn creates a `Blob` in an `after_create` with an `amount` parameter set to the value of `Item`'s `price`. I cannot find out how to run an after_create in minitest, so I mocked up the `Blob` data in setup to inherit from an attribute of `Item`.

I can see that the error comes from line 15 of `item_test.rb`, but I'm not understanding why. I'm creating the `Users`, then the `Items`, and then ***ERROR*** the `Blobs`. I understand the why (I have a db level uniqueness constraint on a combination of user and item) but not the how (because from what I see, I haven't created those `Blobs` - there's no `after_create` called on `Item` when they're created in test), and I suspect that it has to do with the way I'm writing this.

It seems natural to me to conclude that `DatabaseCleaner.start` and `DatabaseCleaner.clean` both start and clean up old test data when the test is run and concluded, but this is obviously not the case. I started using it specifically to avoid this problem, which I was having previously. So I db:drop db:create, and db:schema:load, but once again, I have the same issue. And if it's not that, it's a uniqueness violation on a username, an email, etc......long story short, what is going on with that error?

Sorry if this is so confusing.

Edit: If I uncomment the `after_create` and replace all method references to the `blob` object created through that callback with `blobs` created in my test setup, the tests pass. But I really don't like doing that.

Comment: So while in setup creating Items you are creating Blobs via after create firstly (with user_id and item_id) and then again creating them a few lines later, and they already exist(with exact same user_id and item_id pairs matching). I think you need to remove Blob creation lines from setup and test them separately. Or, as long as this is setup, make those pairs(user_id, item_id) not match at least.

Comment: how can i reference the `blobs` created in `after_create`?

Comment: `@item1.blob`, `@item1.owner.blob`(that's too long) and as long as `@user1` is actually `@item1.owner` then `@user1.blob`

Answer (score 0):

Either uncomment the `after_create` and reference the test objects, or remove the test objects and reference each blob by writing a method that returns the blob owned_by user and item, so that you can write `@item.blob`, and have it return the relevant `blob`.